# Force a class implementing the interface to define a constant

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, interface

I am willing to force my classes to define a constant named COMMAND. If php would allow overriding constants from interfaces in would look like

```
class RequestInterface
{
    const COMMAND = "no-command-specified";
}

class LoginRequest implements RequestInterface
{
    const COMMAND = "loginuser";
    public $username;
    public $password;
}

$request = new LoginRequest();
$request->username = "user";
$request->password = "blah";
```

Obviously this does not work. I am looking for a clean way to make my requests define COMMAND cosntant.

I've been considering the following options:

- Interface defines a getCommand method and my request classes need to implement it and return the command name as a string. But it is too much code per request
- Replace the interface with an abstract class. It looks weird because abstract class is *usually* expected to define at least one method
- Interface becomes abstract class and defines a protected variable $command. It also has a getter method that returns $this->command;. Children override protected property $command. I do not like the way of mixing public VARIABLES (that are supposed to be variable) with a protected VARIABLE that is not really supposed to be modifiable and therefore not suppose to be a variable in the first place.

  ```
  class LoginRequest extends BaseRequest
  {
       protected $command = "loginuser";
       public $username;
       public $password;
  }
  ```

What would be the cleanest way of achieving this?

Comment: What do you mean by "_too much code per request_"? You want to avoid having  to define the interface's method inside implementing classes? I would probably just use that option. In the past, I have also used the second (abstract class) option, but I agree it is unusual without any defined method.

Comment: How about a class with only constants, where you reference to in your current class? This way you always have a constant central

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I wanted my Request objects to be the simplest possible containers of data. I appreciate this approach seems to be the cleanest but defining a method seems to me like a bit too much of code

Comment: @user3790680 This approach centralises the data but does not enforce it in any way

Comment: I know, but I thought enforcing was part of to know sure you got the right data. Indeed it won't help for enforcing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Personally, my choice would be:

```
interface RequestInterface
{
    /**
     * @returns string
     */
    public function getCommand();
}

class LoginRequest implements RequestInterface
{
    public function getCommand() {
        return "loginuser";
    }
   ...
}
```

You can always check that a string is returned with `is_string()` later. There's nothing to stop someone setting COMMAND to a number anyway.

Comment: If you want to use it as a serialised object look at the `JsonSerializable` interface. You can then define what data is returned.